# How to reference a value inside of an Angular directive's link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have defined a `value` called `myValue` for my Angular app.  I would like to access `myValue` from the `link` method of a directive I have, but I haven't been able to make this work.  Here is my code:

```
angular.module('extApp').value('myValue', {
  foo: null,
  bar: null
});

angular.module('extApp')
.directive('myDirective', ['constants', 'myValue', function(constants, myValue) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
      location: '=',
      connectionType: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      ...
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.myFunction = function() {
        // Want to be able to reference my myValue here! For example:
        if (myValue.foo != null && myValue.foo > 0) {
            // myValue.foo doesn't work because it sees myValue as undefined
        }
      }

      scope.myOtherFunction = function() {
        ...
      }

      scope.myFunction();
    }
  }
}]);
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: directly use `myValue `, it should be accessible. that is passed as arguments in the function from where you are returning object with properties like scope, link, controller and all.

Comment: The code above should work as expected. Please, provide details what *I haven't been able to make this work* means.

Comment: `myValue` is appearing as undefined for me in the place where I am trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it inside the function:

```
  scope.myFunction = function() {
    console.log(myValue);
  }
```

It will be injected using angularjs DI into directive function and accessible inside `myFunction` through closure.

Comment: I am trying to access `myValue.foo` and it says `myValue` is undefined...

Comment: put the `console.log(myValue)` just above `return {` inside `function(constants, myValue)`, what does it log?

Comment: Huh.  That's working.  So I had stuck a debugger there and the console tools couldn't see `myValue`.  But I guess that's because it was not injected.  Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome, yes, usually you can't see variables captured with closure in debugger if you don't reference them inside the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `constant` as well. Just define it and pass to your directive. `valueFromYourConstant` - is an example of how you can get access to constant values.

```
angular
    .module('extApp')
    .constant('CONSTANT_NAME', {
        values: {
              "foo": null,
              "bar": null
        }
    })
    .directive('myDirective', ['constants', 'myValue', 'CONSTANT_NAME' function(constants, myValue, CONSTANT_NAME) {
        var valueFromYourConstant = CONSTANT_NAME.values["foo"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the ng-model of the element on which directive is placed by requiring ngModel. Also other scope variables are accessible using scope.variableName

You can refer the below sample code where there are two input fields one for password and one for confirming the password. The directive simply matches the confirmation password to the original password and sets the controller variable passmatch as true or false:

My directive:

```
app.directive('matchPassword', function() {
                    return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    require: 'ngModel',
                        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                        function passwordMatcher(ngModelValue) {

                        if (ngModelValue == scope.password) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('passMatch', true);
                        } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('passMatch', false);
                        }
                        return ngModelValue;
                        }

                        ctrl.$parsers.push(passwordMatcher);
                        }
                    };
                });
```

And my html:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-default">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Minimum of 6 Characters" class="form-control" valid-password required>
                  </div>

    <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="cpassword" ng-model="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm password" class="form-control" match-password required>
                      </div>
```